# How can i prepare nested key value pair list in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I have data in rows like

```
1. {type:"pant", service:"normal", price:"30"}
2. {type:"pant", service:"premium 1", price:"50"}
3. {type:"pant", service:"premium 2", price:"70"}
4. {type:"pant", service:"premium 3", price:"100"}
```

Looking for something like

```
var x = {"pant", [{service:"normal", price:"30"},{service:"premium 1", price:"50"} ,{service:"premium 2", price:"70"}, {service:"premium 3", price:"100"}]}
```

so that I can get all type of services and their price by doing **x['pant']**

Comment: `data in rows` In HTML, or what?

Comment: Most of those `=` should be `:`. The only valid use of a `=` above is the `=` immediately after `var x`.

Comment: I have javascript list of objects where each object has key type, service, price

Comment: Your expected output is not a valid object

Comment: @Eddie I am new to javascript, can you tell me what could be the valid form with similar output

Answer (score 5):

Use array reduce function and create a key by name `pant`. Check if the key exist then push the value of `service` and `price`

Also the expected object is invalid. An object key is separated by a colon (`:`)
in this format

```
obj = {
  key:value
}
```

```js
var data = [{
  type: "pant",
  service: "normal",
  price: "30"
}, {
  type: "pant",
  service: "premium 1",
  price: "50"
}, {
  type: "pant",
  service: "premium 2",
  price: "70"
}, {
  type: "pant",
  service: "premium 3",
  price: "100"
}]

var x = data.reduce(function(acc, curr, currIndex) {
  if (!acc[curr.type]) {
    acc[curr.type] = []
  }

  acc[curr.type].push({
    service: curr.service,
    price: curr.price
  })

  return acc;


}, {});

console.log(x)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `type` as the key of the object and the values are arrays of `service` and `price`, you can use `reduce`

```js
let arr = [{type:"pant", service:"normal", price:"30"},{type:"pant", service:"premium 1", price:"50"},{type:"pant", service:"premium 2", price:"70"},{type:"pant", service:"premium 3", price:"100"}];

let result = arr.reduce((c, {type,...r}) => {
  c[type] = c[type] || [];
  c[type].push(r);
  return c;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```